# Error with MySqlMebershipProvider in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, membership-provider

since two days I am trying to solve this error in the asp.net web site configuration - Provider Section

If you click on "Test" this error comes up:

Provider Management
Could not establish a connection to the database.
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

My web config looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="mydbConnectionString"/>
    <add name="mydbConnectionString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>        
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider" />
    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" autogenerateschema="true"
                 type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
                 connectionStringName="mydbConnectionString"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
                 enablePasswordReset="true"
                 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                 requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                 passwordFormat="Hashed"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                 minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
                 applicationName="LoginControl"
 />
        </providers>           
    </membership>
```

It doesn't show the error for RoleProvider. It only shows when I click "Test" for MySqlMembershipProvier. So I think my connection string has some problems but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just have to do what it says in the exception: Run the equivalent of [aspnet_reqsql utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for MySQL to create the required tables in your database.

Shameless plug: Check out the [Web.Config Role Provider](http://webconfigroles.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex if you want to set up Roles without a database.

Comment: I had checked aspnet_reqsql utility and it says that it is only for MSSQL server DB and I couldn't find the one for MySQL server DB.

Comment: Where did you get the MySQLMembershipProvider? There has to be something in the documentation on how to get up and running.

Comment: I added as reference MySql.Web.dll and MySql.Data.dll into Bin folder of my Project. I got them from MySql Connector/net 5.2.7 which is currently being used for my project. Then I could use MySqlMembershipProvider and MySqlRoleProvider in my web.config.

Comment: I'm not familiar with MySQL at all, but can you connect to the database "normally", i.e. query a table there?

Comment: Yes I can retrieve the data from my tables.

Answer (score 0):

1. aspnet_regsql only works with SQL Server. Not with MySQL
2. To install the membership/roles/profile tables, you would need to manually run the SQL files from .NET Framework folder: {SYSDRIVE\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727}
3. Once you do so, then you can check if the connection is an issue.

Comment: I've manually run the scripts files from MySQL connector 5.2.7 in MySQL Qurey Browser. I can create roles and users in Asp.net Web site Administration tools. But in Provider tab, it still shows the same error when I click "Test".